# Reading a text file (which i already know) and then displaying it in a GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

Okay so my program appears to be very basic, I have one class that inputs the students to a text file and this class has to read them, display them in a GUI so the user can pic which student the want and then a remove method to delete the students from the text file. The problem is that this is way more complex than the stuff that I have ever studied, and I am really in need of help, here is my code for the removing students class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StudentsRemove extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    String messsage="";
    Button buttonView, buttonClose, buttonRemove; // Implements all the buttons 
    Label labelAnswer; // Implements all the different text boxes
    TextField textAnswer;

    StudentsRemove(String name)
    {
        super(name);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(7,7));

        labelAnswer = new Label("Remove Student: ");
        textAnswer = new TextField(""); 
        buttonView = new Button("VIEW STUDENTS");
        buttonRemove = new Button("REMOVE");
        buttonClose = new Button("CLOSE");

        add(labelAnswer);
        add(textAnswer);
        add(buttonView);
        add(buttonRemove);
        add(buttonClose);
        setVisible(true);

        buttonView.addActionListener(this);
        buttonRemove.addActionListener(this);
        buttonClose.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         String s="";

        String str = e.getActionCommand();
        if(str.equals("VIEW STUDENTS"))
        {

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader BuffRe = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Students.txt"));
            StringBuilder StrBu = new StringBuilder();
            String line = BuffRe.readLine(); 

            while (line != null)
            {
                StrBu.append(line);
                StrBu.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = BuffRe.readLine();
                //numStudents++;
            }
                    String everything = StrBu.toString();
                    BuffRe.close();
        }   

        catch(Exception z)
        {
            System.out.println("The Exception Is : " +z);
        }

        }
     }

}
```

I need help displaying them in a GUI once I've read the entire program, and then allowing the user to select one of the students and removing them. I know it's a lot but I am completely lost and don't have an "extensive" knowledge of programming.

Thanks in advance guys.

Cyla.

Comment: Basically, read the file into some kind of List. Manipulate the Kist and when you're ready, save the List back to the file. This reduces some of the overhead and complexity. I'd use a JList to display the individual students, which would allow you to select the ones you want to manipulate....

Comment: The problem is mate, I have no idea how to do that. How do i save it back? I know it's a hassle to explain, but I'm in terrible need of help haha.

Comment: Saving (obviously) is the same process as loading, take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Start by declaring a `JList` and `ListModel` instance variables...

```
private JList studentList;
private DefaultListModel model;
```

This is what will be used to display your information and allow the user to interact with.

Create some methods to update the model...

```
public void addStudent(String student) {
    model.addElement(student);
}

public void deleteStudent(String student) {
    model.removeElement(student);
}
```

Create methods to read and write the student information from and to disk...

```
public List<String> loadStudents() throws IOException {
    List<String> students = new ArrayList<>(25);
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Students.txt"))) {

        String student = null;
        while ((student = br.readLine()) != null) {
            students.add(student);
        }

    } finally {
    }
    return students;
}

public void saveStudents(List<String> students) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Students.txt"))) {

        for (String student : students) {
            bw.write(student);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.flush();

    } finally {
    }
}
```

Then load the student information from the file into the model...

```
protected void save() {
    try {
        List<String> students = loadStudents();
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String student : students) {
            model.addElement(student);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not read students.txt: " + ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    studentList.setModel(model);
}
```

And write a method to save the information from the model to disk...

```
protected void save() {
    List<String> students = new ArrayList<>(model.getSize());
    for (int index = 0; index < model.getSize(); index++) {
        students.add((String)model.get(index));
    }

    try {
        saveStudents(students);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not write students.txt: " + ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Now, obviously, you need to create the `JList` and add it your UI, but I'll leave that up to you.

Take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: wait your code gives me a lot of errors, do you know why?

Comment: Probably because it's not fully complete and is going to require to fill in the missing pieces...

Comment: oh okay cuz you know what you're doing and i didnt wanna mess with it but i put it in and it says "type List does not take parameters"

Comment: Likely you've imported `java.awt.List` and not `java.util.List`

Comment: that definitely fixed the error. and now I have to create another GUI? Cuz I already have one working with buttons and stuff.

Comment: You could combine them, but that's up to you.  It might be easier to build a new one

Comment: but it'll look different to the rest of them right? this is a important project so it's gotta look nice and stuff.

Comment: also dude, it all needs to be off of button clicks and the only way i know how to do that is by using if([string name here].equals("button name")) then do this.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Lists]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Basically, the `JList` will simply show all the students in the file.  When you click on an item in the list, you can use a `ListSelectionListener` to monitor the change and refresh the UI (ie get the selected name and display it in a `JTextField`).  If the user selects the "save" button, you would simply need to update the `ListModel`...

Comment: looking at that is like trying to learn Chinese. Perhaps I'm a little in over my head and really short on time, need to send it off to the UK tomorrow. This is the only class I've had problems with and I really don't understand, is there any way I could just enter a name and have it delete that from the text file? Something a little less complex along those lines? I'm really lost.

Comment: Well, rather than using a `JList`, you could just read the contents into a `List` and add/remove elements directly from it and the write the contents back to the file

Comment: How do I do that/make it display? I really need your help on this mate... and im completely lost

Comment: If you need to display the list, then you're going to need the `JList`.  Getting the content into a `java.util.List` will make manipulating the content as simple as you can get.  You could simply move between elements with a next/prev button, but you would need to maintain a index value to determine the current record...

Comment: the issue is I don't know how to do that :( like at all. I was busy working on other classes so I left this one till the end and I'm clearly regretting that atm. i know it's the whole "do your own homework" on the internet but i actually have no idea what i am doing.